# Working with Photo Library: How do I add/retrieve a location per photo?

Tags: ios8, location, phasset

I'm trying to get the location of a photo via iOS 8's photo library.

The doc says that the PHAsset class has a 'location' attribute.

[image]

So I tried to view the 'location' via Xcode v6.3 attached to my iTouch running iOS 8.3... assessing my iTouch photo library:

> (lldb) po asset 
>   5C9845F2-6BFD-410B-8222-FFBCE5FFD4A8/L0/001 mediaType=1/0,
>   assetSource=6, (3008x2000), creationDate=2015-04-05 22:40:28 +0000,
>   location=0, hidden=0, favorite=0
>
> (lldb) po asset.creationDate 2015-04-05 22:40:28 +0000
>
> (lldb) po asset.location error: :1:1: error: 'PHAsset' does not
>   have a member named 'location' asset.location ^     ~~~~~~~~

Even though I see the 'location' attribute within the 'asset' object, I can't access it...apparently there's no 'location' data.

**Questions:** 
1) Why does the debugger say PHAsset doesn't have the 'location' attribute when I can see that it does (...having a zero value; and is described in the docs)?

2) Assuming that there's no location data with the photo, how do I make my iTouch's (and iPhone) camera record its location?   **Note:** this is a Wi-Fi based iTouch; not an iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds more like a debugger issue.
Try

```
po [asset location]
```

To record location data, just enable location services for the camera app on your iPod touch.

Answer (score 0):

As per my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30281808/195932) you need to import `CoreLocation`.